# Email are sent 3 times when cron job is called

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

This is how I added cron job

```
add_action('init','cliv_create_recurring_schedule');
add_action('cliv_recurring_cron_job','cliv_recurring_cron_function');
function cliv_recurring_cron_function(){
    send_email();
}
function cliv_create_recurring_schedule(){
    //check if event scheduled before
  if(!wp_next_scheduled('cliv_recurring_cron_job'))
   //shedule event to run after every hour
   {
        wp_schedule_event (time(), 'remindextendrequest', 'cliv_recurring_cron_job'); 
   }

}

add_filter('cron_schedules','cliv_cron_add_remindextendrequest');
function cliv_cron_add_remindextendrequest($schedules){
   $schedules['remindextendrequest'] = array(

       'interval' => 86400,
       'display'=> 'RemindExtendRequest'
   );
   return $schedules;
}
```

And everyday I receive 3 emails (same content), so that I think the cron job is called 3 times?.

The first 2 emails arrived at the same time. 
The third email arrived 10 mins later.

I still do not know why. Please help.

UPDATE 1: I noticed that the wp-cron.php is called 70,000 times. Maybe because it is called so many times, it goes wrong? I have just tried to set up cron job in CPanel and see if it can fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using CPanel, Cron Jobs are not set up with code but by panel options. There might very well be a way to set up the Cron Job with code, but it's much easier to just make a php script with what you want to happen, and then set up the cron job to run that script from the CPanel options in the exact intervals that you want.

Comment: Wordpress is also provide default recurrence daily i think do you not need to make a new same  interval like daily. remindextendrequest and daily is same interval. If this helpful for you debug cron https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-cron-manager or using cpanel this article https://www.iceablethemes.com/optimize-wordpress-replace-wp_cron-real-cron-job/